# Elasticsearch bulk upload error with PHP - Limit of total fields [1000] in index has been exceeded

Tags: php, elasticsearch

We are planning use ElasticSearch in one of our projects. Currently, we are testing ElasticSearch 5.0.1 with our data. One issue we are facing is when we are doing a bulk upload from our MySQL tables to elasticsearch following error we are getting...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Limit of total fields [1000] in index [shopfront] has been exceeded
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.checkTotalFieldsLimit(MapperService.java:482) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:343) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.applyRequest(MetaDataMappingService.java:323) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:241) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(ClusterService.java:555) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService$UpdateTask.run(ClusterService.java:896) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:451) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:238) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:201) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

We are using PHP as elasticsearch client to doing the bulk upload from MySQL to Elastic. After doing some googling I got this piece of info - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-2-3-5-x-metricbeat-index-field-limit/66821

Somewhere also I read that using of "index.mapping.total_fields.limit" will fix the thing. But, can't able to understand how to using that in my PHP code. Here is my PHP code.

```
$params = ['body' => []];

$i = 1;
foreach ($productsList as $key => $value) {

    $params['body'][] = [
        'index' => [
            '_index' => 'shopfront',
            '_type' => 'products'
        ],
        'settings' => ['index.mapping.total_fields.limit' => 3000]
    ];

    $params['body'][] = [
        'product_displayname' => $value['product_displayname'],
        'product_price' => $value['product_price'],
        'popularity' => $value['popularity'],
        'lowestcomp_price' => $value['lowestcomp_price']
    ];

    // Every 1000 documents stop and send the bulk request
    if ($i % 1000 == 0) {
        $responses = $client->bulk($params);

        // erase the old bulk request
        $params = ['body' => []];

        // unset the bulk response when you are done to save memory
        unset($responses);
    }

    $i++;
}

// Send the last batch if it exists
if (!empty($params['body'])) {
    $responses = $client->bulk($params);
}
```

NOTE - I've used same code with Elasticsearch 2.4.1 & it's working fine with that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In ES 5, the ES folks decided to limit the number of fields that a mapping type can contain to prevent a mapping explosion. As you've noticed, that limit has been set at 1000 fields per mapping, but you can lift that limit to suit your needs by specifying the `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` setting either at index creation time or by [updating the index settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/indices-update-settings.html), like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/shopfront/_settings' -d '
{
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 3000
}'
```

Note that you also need to ask yourself whether having that many fields is a good thing. Do you need them all? Can you combine some? etc, etc

Comment: if you see I've used ```'settings' => ['index.mapping.total_fields.limit' => 3000]``` in my code above. Is it not right ?

Comment: No, you cannot specify that in your bulk call, you either need to do it at index creation time or simply by updating the index settings as I've shown. It's a one-off call, so you can run that curl and you'll be fine.

Comment: Ok. I did this ```curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/shopfront?pretty' -d'{"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":3,"number_of_replicas":2},"index.mapping.total_fields.limit":50000}}'``` & it worked. Thanks for helping me out.

One doubt - As I've sent only 4 fields in my JSON docs how it's calculating & figuring out that it increases the limit of 2000/3000 ?

Comment: I used that curl command & here is the screenshot of result - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_fPgzLKQF6zOWR1ZmlBUy1JaTQ/view . You can see there are only 15 fields in 'properties' index. Also, there is no another indexes exist in my ES instance except the one I was trying to.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, then. Not sure what's up, but I'll think about it.

Comment: This is happening to me and I also don't have 1000 fields on my index :/, is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This feature was decided in this [github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17357). Two ways to solve this problem:

You can specify a greater value when creating the index:

```
PUT test
{
  "shopfront": {
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000,
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Or if you would like to increase the limit for an existing index:

```
PUT shopfront/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
}
```