# Getting limit of total 1000 fields in index exceeded. Can the document be indexed matching only existing fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to index the document although the fields count is exceeded. Just truncate the missing fields if required. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857060/elasticsearch-bulk-upload-error-with-php-limit-of-total-fields-1000-in-index/40858040#40858040

Comment: I don't want to raise the limit. Just index the document leaving the fields that require being added aside